# Delphi Polymorphism using a "sibling" class type

Tags: delphi, polymorphism

We have an app that makes fairly extensive use of TIniFile. In the past we created our own descendant class, let's call it TMyIniFile, that overrides WriteString. We create one instance of this that the entire app uses. That instance is passed all around through properties and parameters, but the type of all of these is still TIniFile, since that is what it was originally. This seems to work, calling our overridden method through polymorphism, even though all the variable types are still TIniFile. This seems to be proper since we descend from TIniFile.

Now we are making some changes where we want to switch TMyIniFile to descend from TMemIniFile instead of TIniFile. Those are both descendants of TCustomIniFile. We'll also probably be overriding some more methods. I'm inclined to leave all the declarations as TIniFile even though technically our class is no longer a descendant of it, just to avoid having to change a lot of source files if I don't need to.

In every tutorial example of polymorphism, the variable is declared as the base class, and an instance is created of the descendant class and assigned to the variable of the base class. So I assume this is the "right" way to do it. What I'm looking at doing now will end up having the variables declared as, what I guess you'd call a "sibling" class, so this "seems wrong". Is this a bad thing to do? Am I asking for trouble, or does polymorphism actually allow for this sort of thing?

Comment: Declare all your variables to be TMyIniFile is the correct way

Answer (score 6):

`TIniFile` and `TMemIniFile` are distinct classes that do not derive from each other, so you simply cannot create a `TMemIniFile` object and assign it to a `TIniFile` variable, and vice versa.  The compiler won't let you do that.  And using a type-cast to force it will be dangerous.

You will just have to update the rest of your code to change all of the `TIniFile` declarations to `TCustomIniFile` instead, which is the common ancestor for both classes.  That is the "correct" thing to do.

Comment: If you always instantiate TMyIniFile then you should declare all the variables as TMyIniFile in my view. There's nothing to be gained from doing what you suggest and it just obfuscate the code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm of the opposite opinion. All of the variables should be TCustomIniFile, because that is where WriteString() is first exposed, and the code doesn't need to know the details of how WriteString() is implemented. If the code needs to change implementation again in the future, it will be easier to do so if all of the variables are a base class rather than a concrete derived class. It also allows code to be migrated from one concrete class to another on a more flexible time frame.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is your friend - why would you lie to it by using the wrong type ... and if you do lie to it why would you expect it to know what you want it to do?

You should use a base class that you derive from, like `TCustomIniFile`.  I would expect compile issues if you are trying to make assignments which are known at compile time to be wrong.

The different classes have different signatures so the compiler needs to know which class it is using to call the correct method or access the correct property.  With virtual methods the different classes setup their own implementation of those methods so that the correct one is called - so using a pointer to a base type when you call the virtual method it calls that method in the derived type because it is in the class vtable.

So if the code does compile, it's very likely that the compiler will not be doing the right thing ...